# Accessing Nmap flags in Nmap script (NSE)

Tags: nmap, nse

I'm finishing an Nmap script that needs to create a file as part of the output (an image) which doesn't make sense to print or embed in the standard Nmap output. Currently I'm naming the output `image.jpg`, but I'd like use the input of the `-oA/-oN/-oX/-oS/-oG` flag to make the name of the output file less likely to conflict with anything in the current directory.

I've done some digging but I haven't found any way to access the flags passed to Nmap.

Is it possible to access these flags from inside an NSE, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a way in the current [NSE API](https://nmap.org/book/nse-api.html) to access that information. Most of the scripts that save output to files take a filename or target directory as a script-arg. I've just opened [a new issue](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/445) on Github to address this idea, so we'll see if we can improve this in the future.